# Tim-Api REVERSAL Function

Tags: java, android, payment

I want to process a refund with tim-api.
but after the refund request I get an error of "unknown reference number".

I couldn't find a parameter to send as a reference number.

How can I fix this?

```
terminal.transactionAsync(TransactionType.REVERSAL, new Amount(10.0, Currency.EUR));
```

Output:

> SIXML_UNKNOWN_REFERENCE_NUMBER

[Tim-Api](https://six-tim.github.io/timapi/doc/java/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String trxRefNum = "Your last transaction Ref Number";

TransactionRequest transactionRequest = new TransactionRequest();
TransactionData transactionData = new TransactionData();

transactionData.setSixTrxRefNum(trxRefNum);
transactionRequest.setTransactionData(transactionData);
try {
     SixUtils.terminal.transaction(TransactionType.REVERSAL, transactionRequest);
    } catch (TimException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you. It'works